# Conditional css class with if in razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi i have question about Razor.

I want to conditional class using `if` statment but i have a weird result, let me show:

```
@{ var row_odd = false; }
@for (int y = 0; y <= Model.Count() - 1; y++)
{
    <div class='at-column-item @if (row_odd) { @("at-column-item-odd") }'>@row_odd</div>
    row_odd = !row_odd;
}
```

If i run this code i always have the `at-column-item-odd` inserted in all the divs.

But if I use this code i have the rigth result:

```
@{ var row_odd = false; }
@for (int y = 0; y <= Model.Count() - 1; y++)
{
    <div class='at-column-item @(row_odd ? "at-column-item-odd" : "")'>@row_odd</div>
    row_odd = !row_odd;
}
```

I'm trying to find why the `if` statment does not work correctly in the string of the css, because if i move to another place work perfectly.

Any idea?

Comment: I would suggest instead of manually setting the class on even and odd rows, to use the following CSS and add the striped-table class to the table:  
.striped-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: silver;
}

Comment: OT just a tip: instead of `y <= count - 1` usually this is used: `y < count`.

Comment: Well thx for answer but i really want to know why the if statement is not working.